# How to hide Newsletter plugin submenus from the Dashboard?

Tags: sub-menu

I would like to hide some submenus from the Dashboard for non admin users. I'm using the `remove_submenu_page` function but I'm not using it properly since it doesn't work and sub menus are still displayed. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

I'm trying to hide sub menus from a plugin called Newsletter for non admins :

- wp-admin/admin.php?page=newsletter_main_index
- wp-admin/admin.php?page=newsletter_main_main
- wp-admin/admin.php?page=newsletter_main_diagnostic
- wp-admin/admin.php?page=newsletter_subscription_profile

Here's the code I used in functions.php but I can't get it right:

```
    function ns_remove_admin_menus() {
        global $menu;
        global $current_user;
        if ($current_user->ID != 1) {
            remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php?page=', 'newsletter_main_index' );
            remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'newsletter_main_index' );
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_init', 'ns_remove_admin_menus', 999 );
```

Any idea how I could make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the action `admin_menu` as opposed to `admin_init`. You also need to adjust your use of `remove_submenu_page` to match the way Newsletter adds menu items:

```
remove_submenu_page( 'newsletter_main_index', 'newsletter_main_index' );
remove_submenu_page( 'newsletter_main_index', 'newsletter_main_main' );
remove_submenu_page( 'newsletter_main_index', 'newsletter_main_diagnostic' );
remove_submenu_page( 'newsletter_main_index', 'newsletter_subscription_profile' );
```

Comment: Tried `remove_submenu_page( 'admin.php', 'newsletter_main_index' ); remove_submenu_page( 'admin', 'newsletter_main_index' );
add_action('admin_menu', 'ns_remove_admin_menus', 999 );` with no luck

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole of "Newsletter" from the admin menu, or just sub menu items from "Newsletter"?

Comment: Only submenus items (the ones listed in my initial post).

Comment: Gotcha. See revised answer.

Comment: I thought the id slug for the parent menu was admin.php , thanks